# Localize and change a date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that i get from an excel file that gets regularly updated.
In one column I have a date as datetime64. It is not used as an index.
The entries span from 2015 to the current date.
Sometimes, people make errors entering the dates. So I know there is one entry where the date is 1945-11-05 which correctly is 2015-11-05. This row of the cell changes everytime the excel-file is updated, so i can not localize it with a row/column-number.
I want to update this cell to the correct date.
How can I localize this cell and change the year?

The dataframe looks like this:

```
article_number order_number date         quantity
1234           abcd         2015-08-16   123
1234           xyz          2015-09-01   456
2342           qsdf         2015-01-04   12
4223           qwerty       1945-11-05   155
0815           qwertz       2016-01-01   667
```

Comment: Do you need replace only one date (few dates)? Is possible dates are like `1946-01-01`, `1945-08-16` and is necessary change only first 3 chars? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

To localize:

```
In [128]: df.loc[df['date'].dt.year < 2015]
Out[128]:
   article_number order_number       date  quantity
3            4223       qwerty 1945-11-05       155
```

To change:

```
df.loc[df['date'].dt.year < 2015, 'date'] = \
    df.loc[df['date'].dt.year < 2015, 'date'].map(lambda x: x.replace(year=2015))
```

Result:

```
In [137]: df
Out[137]:
   article_number order_number       date  quantity
0            1234         abcd 2015-08-16       123
1            1234          xyz 2015-09-01       456
2            2342         qsdf 2015-01-04        12
3            4223       qwerty 2015-11-05       155
4             815       qwertz 2016-01-01       667
```

Answer (score 1):

For localize use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df['date'].dt.year < 2015])
   article_number order_number       date  quantity
3            4223       qwerty 1945-11-05       155
```

For replace first 3 chars is possible use (if years are between `2015` and `2019`):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('201' + df['date'].astype(str).str[3:])
print (df)
   article_number order_number       date  quantity
0            1234         abcd 2015-08-16       123
1            1234          xyz 2015-09-01       456
2            2342         qsdf 2015-01-04        12
3            4223       qwerty 2015-11-05       155
4             815       qwertz 2016-01-01       667
```

Or:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('201' + df['date'].dt.strftime('%y-%m-%m').str[1:])
print (df)
   article_number order_number       date  quantity
0            1234         abcd 2015-08-08       123
1            1234          xyz 2015-09-09       456
2            2342         qsdf 2015-01-01        12
3            4223       qwerty 2015-11-11       155
4             815       qwertz 2016-01-01       667
```

Also is possible use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and replace only values less as `2015`:

```
m = df['date'].dt.year < 2015
df['date'] = df['date'].mask(m, pd.to_datetime('201' + df['date'].dt.strftime('%y-%m-%m').str[1:]))
print (df)
   article_number order_number       date  quantity
0            1234         abcd 2015-08-16       123
1            1234          xyz 2015-09-01       456
2            2342         qsdf 2015-01-04        12
3            4223       qwerty 2015-11-11       155
4             815       qwertz 2016-01-01       667
```

But if want change only one date use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].replace(pd.to_datetime('1945-11-05'), 
                                pd.to_datetime('2015-11-05'))
print (df)
   article_number order_number       date  quantity
0            1234         abcd 2015-08-16       123
1            1234          xyz 2015-09-01       456
2            2342         qsdf 2015-01-04        12
3            4223       qwerty 2015-11-05       155
4             815       qwertz 2016-01-01       667
```